# Makefile on windows: unable to locate cmd.exe directory

Tags: windows, makefile, cmd, pipe, cat

I am facing an issue when I try to run a Makefile on windows (working with Cygwin).
I have this line of code:

```
cat command.bat | "$(cmddir)"
```

cmddir was defined as `cmddir       := /C/Windows/System32/cmd.exe`

Which is now throwing this error:

```
cat command.bat | "/C/Windows/System32/cmd.exe"
/bin/sh: /C/Windows/System32/cmd.exe: No such file or directory
```

Although cmd.exe is located under `C:\Windows\System32`

Any hints?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm using Cygwin, I just had to adapt the path to cmd.exe from `/C/Windows/System32/cmd.exe` to `cygdrive/C/Windows/System32/cmd.exe`

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with cygwin. Did you try adding a : (double colon) after C (the drive letter)?
Also, what happens when you do `ls C/Windows/System32` ?

Comment: Adding a double colon didn't change anything. `ls C/Windows/System32` returns the error: `no such file or directory`. But you gave me a hint. I tried pwd under `C:\Windows\system32` and it returned `/cygwin/c/WINDOWS/system32` so I modified the cmddir value to that and it worked!! Thanks a lot!